# Unable to read data from Parquet Hive table via Spark 1.6

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I am trying to read data from hive table stored in Parquet format. I am using MapR distribution. After reading the data, when I try to do any operation e.g. df.show(3), it throws java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7. If the table storage is changed to ORC, then it works.

And also, I am trying to read from tables in shared cluster. Therefore I can't change anything in the source table.

The Hive table structure,

```
CREATE TABLE employee_p(
  emp_id bigint,
  f_name string,
  l_name string,
  sal double)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'maprfs:/user/hive/warehouse/sptest.db/employee_p'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='true',
  'numFiles'='1',
  'numRows'='4',
  'rawDataSize'='16',
  'totalSize'='699',
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1550203019')
```

Java code,

```
    String warehouseLocation = args[0];
    String query1 = "select emp_id, f_name, l_name, sal from sptest.employee_p";

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Parquet Table");
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    HiveContext hc = new HiveContext(jsc);

    DataFrame df = hc.sql(query1);

    df.printSchema();
    df.show(10);
```

The job submit command,

```
    $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class com.app.hive.FetchFromParquetTable \
    ${APP_HOME}/SparkTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar maprfs:/user/hive/warehouse \
    --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster \
    --conf "spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat=true" \
    --conf "spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown=false" \
    --queue myqueue
```

Excpetion,

```
19/02/14 21:08:23 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, lgpbd1523.gso.aexp.com): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
        at org.apache.parquet.bytes.BytesUtils.bytesToLong(BytesUtils.java:250)
        at org.apache.parquet.column.statistics.LongStatistics.setMinMaxFromBytes(LongStatistics.java:50)
        at org.apache.parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.fromParquetStatistics(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:255)
        at org.apache.parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.fromParquetMetadata(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:550)
        at org.apache.parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.readParquetMetadata(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:527)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:430)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:385)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.initializeInternalReader(ParquetRecordReader.java:157)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.initialize(ParquetRecordReader.java:140)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.SqlNewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.SqlNewHadoopRDD.compute(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are facing this problem while reading the table, you can confirm from your spark UI, since spark is lazy when you triggered an action it actually started reading the table and you have encountered this problem.

I am facing the same issue while reading the table created by hive with parquet and snappy compression using spark 2.1.0 version with MapR distribution.

Can you try changing the emp_id datatype from bigint to String?